# Improve a sliced function (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

> Slice is a powerful access index for elements of an array available in
>   numpy. This solution is one of the most efficient. The image is
>   initially create with zeros and then filled with those on even lines
>   and then on odd lines, always scan the image every two pixels.
>
> Implement an isccsym function using slice and handle complex arrays.
>   Remember that it is enough to test half the array, since if
>   `F(a)==F(-a)`, there is no need to compare `F(-a)` with `F(a)` again.

```
def isccsym(F):

    G = np.copy(F)
    G[0,0] = np.conjugate(F[0,0])   
    G[0,1:] = np.conjugate(F[0,:0:-1])
    G[1:,0] = np.conjugate(F[:0:-1,0])
    G[1:,1:] = np.conjugate(F[1:,1:][::-1,::-1])

    if G.dtype == np.complex:
        Gaux = np.sum(([G.imag]))

    return (abs(F-G)< 10E-4).all()
```

Can someone help me? I need to improve her processing time even more.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate the whole `G` matrix at once, not building it by parts. That should speed up your operation a bit at least. Further, the calculation of Gaux is not used for anything and could therefore be removed, leading to:

```
def isccsym(F):
    G = F.conj().T
    return (abs(F-G) < 10E-4).all()
```

However, this implementation does not use slice.

For a solution that is using slices and that is only checking the relevant elements, as per the given hint, it is possible to do:

```
def isccsym(F):
    row, col = F.shape
    sym = (row == col)
    while sym and row > 0:
        row -= 1
        sym = (abs(F[row, row:] - F[row:, row].conj()) < 10e-4).all()
    return sym
```

Comment: Thank you, your you're right, but because you can only use slicing, it's not feasible to use, but I'll use that later.

Comment: @Arlequina I have updated the answer with a solution that follows the given requirements, as far as I can understand.